# Laravel - Como popular uma combobox no evento 'on load' de uma view (blade)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, view, combobox

Preciso popular uma combobox com dados provenientes de banco de dados, mas  este preenchimento deveria ocorrer durante o carregamento da view.

Como a view não é o lugar correto para se escrever código, como alimentar a combobox? Através de um método em um controller? Qual o 'mecanismo' para responder ao evento 'on load' por exemplo?

A título de demonstração, teria o formulário abaixo numa view blade:

```
<form>
 Cliente: 
<Select>
    <option>Fulano de Tal</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para alimentar um combobox pelo Laravel 5 recomendo você installar pelo composer o pacote [Laravel collective](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html) para criar formulários pela facade Form e facilitar o trabalho com formulários.
Se o combobox necessita ser alimentado por valores consultados no banco de dados, você deve fazer a consulta no controller utilizando o model dentro do método que carrega a view.

Exemplo:

Imagine que tem um módel de Estados e quer alimentar o combobox

```
$estado = Estado::lists('uf','id')->all();
```

passando para a view

```
return view('sua view',compact('estado'));
```

ou

```
return view('sua view',get_defined_vars());
```

Criando o combobox na view e exibindo os dados com o laravel collective:

```
{!! Form::select('estados',['' => 'selecione ...'+$estado],'',['id' => 'estados']) !!}
```

Uma das vantagens em criar os formulários utilizando o laravel colective é para edição de informações. Quando você que editar os dados de um usuário por exemplo, você tem que fazer a consulta e preencher todos os campos do formulário com seus respectivos dados.

Por exemplo:

Para preencher todos os campos de um formulário de usuário você faz a consulta no método, manda o objeto para a view e ...

```
{!! Form::model($seuObjetoUsuario) !!}

{!! Form::text('nome',app('request')->get('nome')) !!}
```

....
Essas linhas mostram como você preenche um formulário que tem o campo nome utilizando o objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Como obter o valor específico dá key Field, mas listar toda a lista caso a pessoa queira mudar o Estado?
No CakePHP usuária uma list assim:

```
$cidade= $this->cidade->estado->find('list',['keyField' => 'idcidade', 'valueField' => 'nome_estado','limit' => 20]);
```

No Laravel como eu faço?